# Question on jsLint error: "Don't make functions within a loop"

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm reading DOM Scripting by Jeremy Keith and testing the code in jsLint

1. In the code sample here it i'm getting an error that says ""Don't make functions within a loop".
2. When I try to fix it, I seem to be losing the scope of **this**
3. I need to see an example of how to fix this error.
4. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkdsleeper/ejvMj/

Thanks In Advance

sleeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this where you define local functions outside the loop:

```
(function highlightRows() {

    "use strict";

    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName) { return false; }

    function handleMouseOver () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "crimson";
        this.style.color = "#ffffff";
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        this.style.color = "#000000";
    }


    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl_example"), // get the table
        rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr"), // get all the table rows
        i,
        current_row;

    // loop through rows adding style info to the mouseover/mouseout events
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        current_row = rows[i];

        // cancel highlight of th row
        if (current_row.parentNode.tagName === "THEAD") { 
            continue;
        }

        current_row.onmouseover = handleMouseOver;
        current_row.onmouseout = handleMouseOut;
    }    
}())
```

Working in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aKfWs/.

Comment: this is cool also. it is easier (for me) to follow. but I also like @Ivan's approach (using the variable). Does it just come down to taste or are there performance issues. Thanks again.

Comment: It's probably mostly personal preference, but I say why execute a function in order to get another function?  Why not just assign the function you want as it's both simpler and likely faster.  Locally declared, named functions are very useful.  I use them all the time whenever I want to call the same local function from more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
var initMouseover = function() {
    return function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "crimson";
        this.style.color = "#ffffff";
    };
};
```

and then in for loop you have:

```
current_row.onmouseover = initMouseover();
```

I test it on link you post and it seems to work and also doesn't show this error anymore.

Comment: That'll do it. But I have a few questions: 1. WHy did you store the function in a variable? 2. How come this holds it scope? thanx.

Comment: The only reason I return anonymous function is that I can control scope of initMouseover with call or apply

Comment: You don't need to generate a unique function for each event handler. Remove that nested function from `initMouseover` and just assign `current_row.onmouseover = initMouseover;` That will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine as is.  The `this` inside your event handler functions refers to the DOM object that fired the event, which is a `<tr>` element.  Thus you can change your styles by modifying the properties of `this`.  You can access the same object via a function parameter as well.

```
current_row.onmouseover = function (event) {
            console.log(this == event.currentTarget);
}
```

That will log `true` to the console because `this` and `event.currentTarget` are the same DOM element object.

But yes, you are correct in that in the scope of your `for` loop, `this` (which you don't use in that exact scope) is the top level `window` object, but within the event handler functions, `this` is a different object.

Comment: OK, but according to jsLint they don't like the function INSIDE of the loop. This is why I need to see a revised code example. Bear with me, I'm a noob :)

Comment: JSLint does NOT complain about a function inside the loop because in the version of the code here you DON'T have one.  See how inside your `for` loop the word `function` never appears?  You have already refactored the click handler function definitions to separate named functions prior to the loop.  If you were assigning them as anonymous function defined within the loop, then JSLint might warn about that, but you aren't.