# Jquery plugin for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering this code (part of a JQuery plugin I'm developing) :

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
    var btn = $("<a></a>").addClass(class1)
                          .addClass(class2 + counter);
    btn.click(function() {
        $.fn.myPlugin.Click(counter);
    });
    myDiv.append(btn);
 }
```

Where `btn` is an `<a>` tag to which I had CSS classes (to make it look like a button) and a click event calling one of my plugin function with `counter` (1,2,3) as a parameter, and `myDiv` is the `<div>` containing my 3 created buttons.

The problem is that all my `<a>` tags created will call the function with `4` as a parameter, and I have no idea why.

Comment: It's because the code within the click handler is executed after the loop has finished .: `counter` is always the highest value it will iterate to.

Comment: Yes.  The anonymous click function has access to the variable counter through closure.

Comment: Does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103720/question-on-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i could use this to solve thise problem

```
btn.click({ arg: counter }, function(event) {
    $.fn.myPlugin.Click(event.data.arg);
});
```

Comment: cool.  You should give answer credit to someone.  If that someone was you, give it to yourself.  It's good for keeping the site organized and will prevent more people from trying to answer this one.

Comment: I was planning on doing that, but i have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to create a closure but this is what I've come to do when I run into a problem like this.

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
    var btn = $("<a></a>").addClass(class1)
                          .addClass(class2 + counter);

    (function(b,c) {
        b.click(function() {
            $.fn.myPlugin.Click(c);
        });
    })(btn,counter);

    myDiv.append(btn);
 }
```

Passing in `btn` probably isn't necessary as it will be passed by reference anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It does work, but i found something else that could be considered better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to deal with closure in a loop.  The reason this works is `i` has to be evaluated in order to create the function which logs its current value.  You could create your own makeClickHandlerFunction in your for loop in a similar manner.

```
var funcs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   var createFunc = function(x){
      return function(){console.log(x)};
   };
   funcs.push(createFunc(i));
}
funcs[0](); //logs 0
funcs[1](); //logs 1
```

Comment: By the way, travis's answer basically does this, but never names the createFunc function--he just executes it unnamed.